# Organizing controllers and views in subfolders - best practice

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am thinking through the best practice for organizing my code in an **ASP.NET Core MVC** app. I have two types of users, Doctors and Nurses, would it be best practice to organize all my Doctors and Nurses controllers/views in its own Doctors and Nurses sub folders within the controllers/views folder?

Controllers:

- Controllers/Doctors/HomeController.cs
- Controllers/Nurses/HomeController.cs

Views:

- Views/Doctors/Home/Index.cshtml & other View files
- Views/Nurses/Home/Index.cshtml & other View files

The reason for this is because at each of the Doctors/Nurses sub folder level I want to have its own shared folder for a _viewstart file.

1. Is there a better best practice for this situation?
2. Also, within my controllers, how do I get to the subfolder level
   View files?
   The only way that I have found is to explicitly specify them:

```cs
public string Index()
{
    return View("~/Views/Doctors/Home/Index.cshtml");
}
```

3. If I want my default route to go to the
   Doctors/HomeController/Index page is this how I specify the default
   route in my startup.cs file. It doesn't seem to work.

```cs
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "default",
      template: "Doctors/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

4. Lastly, as I had mentioned that I want to have a different
   `_ViewStart.cshtml` for each of the subfolders. Would this work/is it acceptable?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to play with the Core MVC stuff yet. Has it done away with the concept of areas?

Comment: @CraigW. Thanks for this suggestion, I will update with my solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Big Thanks to @Craig W. for suggesting Areas. Unlike in older versions of MVC, with Core there is no formal "Areas" option when you right click on the Project. You can however create a folder and name it "Areas". Within the Controllers you can decorate each controller with **[Area("Doctors")]** to specify the controller for within the Areas.

As far as the startup.cs, I was able to use the following:

```cs
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "areaRoute",
      template: "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}");


    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "default",
      template: "{area=Doctors}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
});
```

Comment: Could you explain it in more detail? What exactly looks like the project tree + the controller code + the view tree?

Comment: This may have been the case back then, but it is available in visual studio now.  Right click project  > Add  > New Scaffold Item.

Answer (score 6):

If you wish to use subfolders for your views or partials, the syntax is

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View("~/Views/Doctors/Index.cshtml");
}
```

Comment: While your code may provide the answer to the question, please add context around it so others will have some idea what it does and why it is there.